# Can't set backgroundColor property of container in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

```
var newHBox:VBox = new VBox();
newHBox['width'] = 20;
newHBox['height'] = 30;
newHBox['backgroundColor'] = "#FF0000";
container.addChild(newHBox);
```

or

```
var newHBox:VBox = new VBox();
newHBox.width = 20;
newHBox.height = 30;
newHBox.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
container.addChild(newHBox);
```

I can't understand why I can't set the `backgroundColor` property, i get an error:

```
access of possibly undefined property through a reference with static type mx.containers.VBox
```

if I use the first example of code, then there are no error, but the backgroundColor still doesn't apply, the `styleName` applies well, can you tell me why the backgroundColor can't be setted?

Comment: the background colour is an inherited property. but look at this website it may help http://www.dickbaldwin.com/actionScript/ActionScript0130/ActionScript0130.htm

Answer (score 1):

the backgroundColor is a style property so you should use:

```
newHBox.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0xFF0000);
```